# Связка nginx php-fpm, 502 ошибка на некоторых страницах recv() failed (104: connection reset by peer), как решить?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

nginx 1.20.2 php-fpm 7.4
На некоторых страницах сайта появляется 502 ошибка при открытии, в логах

включил логи php-fpm там пусто, стоит ispmanager, конфиг php-fpm стандартный

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10
pm.max_requests = 500
listen = /var/www/php-fpm/1.sock
listen.mode = 0660
listen.owner = produser
listen.group = www-data
user = produser
group = produser
chdir = /
include = /opt/php74/etc/php-fpm.d/site.d/domen.ru.conf
include = /opt/php74/etc/php-fpm.d/user.d/produser.conf
```

nginx.config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  24;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
#use epoll;
#multi_accept on;


error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections  18024;
multi_accept on;
use epoll;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  265;


    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;
        client_max_body_size 1128m;


fastcgi_read_timeout 500s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 500s;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 500s;
keepalive_requests 15000;

proxy_buffering on; # по умолчанию
proxy_buffer_size 124k;
proxy_buffers 32 124k; # до 132K + ядерные буфера
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;


tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;


#    keepalive_requests 256;
    reset_timedout_connection off;
#keepalive_requests 1500;



        server {
                server_name localhost;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
        location @fallback {
                error_log /dev/null crit;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                access_log off ;
        }
        }
}




   server {
тут серт пути и прочее
    
    # Прочие настройки
client_max_body_size            100m;
client_body_buffer_size         128k;
client_header_timeout           3m;
client_body_timeout             3m;
send_timeout                    3m;
client_header_buffer_size       1k;
large_client_header_buffers     4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 864000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 864000;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 864000;
proxy_read_timeout 864000;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|webp|bmp|woff|csv)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }
    
   
    location / {
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|webp|bmp|woff|csv)$ {
            expires 365d;
    }
      
      rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api.php?_d=$1&ajax_custom=1&$args last;
      try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|webp|bmp|woff|csv)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            expires 24h;
        }
  }
#   Правиле rewrite для модуля SEO
            location @fallback {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$ /index.php?$args last;
    }
    
    listen 194.26.25.203:443 ssl;
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@cscart.domen.ru";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/7.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Интернет копаю 4 день, перепробовал все что только можно не помогает. Сделал копию сайта на поддомене, там эти страницы открываются корректно

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону оптимизации таймаутов fastcgi_read_timeout, кол-ва соединений net.core.somaxconn и процессов PHP pm.max_children, pm.process_idle_timeout, pm.max_requests.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что image падал при работе с некоторыми карттинками, перешли на gd вопрос решился